# Do something on 1st click, then do something different on 2nd click?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find out a way of doing this but not entirely sure its possible. I have a div called 'messages_nav' and once clicked it toggles/displays another div called 'drop_down_column3'. The general idea is that once 'messages_nav' is clicked it shows a type of drop down box, but then if the user clicks the parent div/'messages_nav' a second time i want them to be taken to a URL address.

could anyone possibly show me how to do this.

here's the jQuery i already have controlling the toggle function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(function() {
       $('.messages_nav').click(function() {
           $('.drop_down_column3').toggle();
           return false; 
       });        
   });
</script>
```

Comment: use a boolean variable and a if statement.

Comment: What about 3rd time? or is it done after second time? Or you want to alternate the functionality every other click?

Comment: well it would be a loop, the first time the drop down box shows, the second time they click they are taken to the link, and then it starts again/restes

Comment: @user3080996 What do you mean by taken to a link? redirecting from the same page?

Answer (score 2):

```
  var firstClick = true;

  $('.messages_nav').click(function() {

       if(firstClick){
           // do first click stuff
           firstClick = false;
       } else {
           // do second (and beyond?) click stuff
       }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another variable to keep track of the amount of clicks, then use a conditional to perform the desired operation.

```
   var clickCount = 0;

   $(function() {
       //this does the reset mentioned in your comment
       clickCount = (clickCount == 2) ? 0:clickCount;
       $('.messages_nav').click(function() {
           if(clickCount == 0){
              $('.drop_down_column3').toggle();
           }else if(clickCount == 1){
              //do something else on second click;
           }
           clickCount++;
       });        
   });
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/r663L/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use a third variable, set it to false at the beginning , the set it to true once it clicked thee first time. Then verify if the variable is true and do your second thing

Answer (score 0):

I would use this approach since you'll probably want to use different styles for the different states anyway.

```
$('.message_nav').on('click', function(){

  var $this = $(this);

  $this.toggleClass('expanded');

  if ($this.is('.expanded')) {
    console.log('The message nav is expanded!');
  } else {
    console.log('The message nav is not expanded!');
  }

});
```

Here's a quick demo: http://jsbin.com/UxUGEcey/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery one metheod combined with on event as:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(function() {
       $('.messages_nav').one("click", function() {
           $('.drop_down_column3').toggle();

            $('.messages_nav').on("click", function() {
                //this code will execute on second click and further clicks 
            });

           return false; 
       });        
   });
</script>
```